# Not able to pass Pass dynamic data from a form to api using curl

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have a form through which i wish to capture values and pass it into api in json format for that i am using the following code.

```
<?php
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$location = $this->input->post('location');
$age = $this->input->post('age');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
    'name' => $name,
    'location' => $location,
    'age' => $age
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Apikey: ***";
$headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

print_r($http_status);

echo "<br>";

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

I am getting the following error

For http_status i am getting error

> 400

And for $result i am getting error

> [Invalid Json: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting
>   double-quote to start field name at [Source:
>   akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@1a18f8fc; line: 3,
>   column: 3]]

In order to resolve the above mentioned issue if i try to give double-quote then i am getting php syntax error

Can anyone please tell me how to send the data successfully

Answer (score 0):

Don't invent the wheel. Use `json_encode` when passing data:

```
$post_fields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'location' => $location,
    'age' => $age
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_fields));
```

Comment: i am getting this error:  This exception has been logged with id 73jbj3e8b.